# Win API GetUserName returns SYSTEM

Tags: c++, winapi, service

I have this method for getting user name of current logged in user, It works fine when I run my application as console application, But when I run it as a windows service, It gives me `SYSTEM` as user name! Any Idea to achieve my desired behavior even if I run my application as windows service?

```
bool GetCurrentUserName(std::wstring& userName)
{
    const int INFO_BUFFER_SIZE = 32767;
    TCHAR infoBuf[INFO_BUFFER_SIZE] = L"";
    DWORD bufCharCount = INFO_BUFFER_SIZE;

    if (GetUserName(infoBuf, &bufCharCount))
    {
        userName = std::wstring(infoBuf);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: That is the standard and *well documented* behavior of services, by default they *all* run with the `SYSTEM` user.

Comment: Now, what is your *real* problem? *Why* do you need your service to run as another user? What is the *actual* problem that's supposed to solve?

Comment: there is a service which gets logged in user name and send it to server and receive some data based on that user name.

Comment: what if multiple users logged in ?

Comment: You are going to need to about Windows user names and the fact that processes, including services, can run under different users.

Comment: @RbMm I Haven't handled that yet :) (Honestly I just understood that)

Comment: Note, the accepted answer of the linked duplicate is not a good approach. Use one of the other answers that utilize `WTSQuerySessionInformation()` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you ! I still haven't got time to fix that issue, anyway thanks for the info.

Answer (score 5):

Since there can be 0, 1 or more users logged in, you need [`LsaEnumerateLogonSessions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/ntsecapi/nf-ntsecapi-lsaenumeratelogonsessions). For every user, call [`LsaGetLogonSessionData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/ntsecapi/nf-ntsecapi-lsaenumeratelogonsessions) to get the user name.

Comment: How to get the user-name of the active-user, the one currently viewing the desktop?

Answer (score 0):

MSDN document says "Retrieves the name of the user associated with the current thread."
`GetUserName` can only get users of the current thread. The user of the service is "SYSTEM".

Comment: Unless of course the service is configured to run as a different user. `LocalService` is also common.